# WordPress - update_post_meta not saving

Tags: wordpress, save, metadata

I am trying to save some simple meta data on a per page basis, but have discovered that the update_post_meta is not seeming to actually save.

I have tried to run this simple test case, then check the actual database (wp_postmeta table) to see if it works:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'parallax_test','true'); //Echoing out $post_id does give me a correct post id
```

When I then query the database, nothing shows up. I am completely stumped as the codex and other tutorials show that I am using the update_post_meta function correctly.
And yes, this function is being called as a simple echo/die test before and after it work fine.

*Side note - I am able to save/retrieve meta data just fine using the 'custom fields' box in the admin. However, I need to be able to use my own meta box and data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turned out to be a typo on my part. In another function I had accidentally used:

```
$post-ID
```

instead of

```
$post->ID
```

Oops...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
global $post;

/* Your Codes Here*/

update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'parallax_test','true');
```

Comment: Yeah I did try that at one point. But not actually necessary since the post id is already passed into the save_meta function. I figured out the issue. Thanks for the quick help though!